# Size of the marker as errorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, errorbar

I would use the size of the marker itself as errorbar. I mean that the upper edge of the marker should be the upper limit of the errorbar and the lower edge the lower limit.
It is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a specific reason not to use the implemented [error bar](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html) functions? Apart from this, are the error measures symmetric? Which marker do you intend to use?

Comment: Just for esthetic purpose, the error bar will overlap and it is not clear the limits. So using the size of the mraker itself I think it will appear more clear. Yes the error are simmetric, and now I use the 'p' marker, so a pentagon shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to have a varying markersize, you have to plot errorbar and scatter separately.

Second, the markersize in scatter is the area of the circle. Therefore, the markersize scale with the size of the errorbar as

markersize ~ error^2

The specific size as it looks in the figure depends a lot of things, like ylim, xlim, figure's dimensions etc.

The best bet is to define a multiplier, and keep changing it until the border of marker met the errorbar's cap. In the following example, `multiplier = 1550` will do the job.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 2)
errors = [1,5]
y = np.sin(x) + errors
multiplier = 1550
markersize = [(i ** 2)*multiplier for i in errors] 
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=errors, fmt='-ok',linewidth = 1, capsize=20, elinewidth=3)
plt.scatter(x, y, s = markersize)
```

[image]